# Unable to locate oozie jobs' attempts logs flies location (stderr and stdout)

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, oozie, hue

I am working on a project that requires using all logs of any oozie workflow and any job in YARN.
I was able to find yarn logs in hdfs tmp/logs, and some oozie logs files through its API, but I was I unable to locate Mapreduce jobs' attempts logs 
files
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/du0EE.png
Do you guys may have any idea where are those files kept?
Thank you!

I already searched through oozie api, in its server and in hdfs' tmp/logs, it doesn't seem to be there.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can get the whole YARN Application logs.

1. Through YARN URL > Applications > Search for the Application Id of interest > Click on the appId to view the details > You can click on number of mappers in the details table (hyperlink) to view the details of each mappers and logs of each map attempts and so are the reducers.
2. Through YARN commands, `yarn logs -applicationId <Application Id>`. More additional options for these commands [HERE](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#logs)

Also, to check the status of the attempts, you can use the commands listed out [HERE](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#applicationattempt)